# Chemical Potential of a Fermionic System

Tags: fermions, chemical-potential, fermi-energy, fermi-liquids

If the chemical potential of a fermionic system is $0$ at temperature $T=0$, will it be zero at any arbitrary finite temperature?

Comment: Can you explain why that should be the case? The zero-point of a scale measuring energies like the Fermi energy is pretty arbitrary no?

Comment: No, at finite temperature it will move. However, if the chemical potential of a fermionic system is zero, then either it is not a conserved quantity and can be created and destroyed with impunity (then its chemical potential is strictly zero always, however, this is extremely unlikely: we have no example of a fermion that behaves this way), or there are no fermion particles, in which case the chemical potential is not really well-defined. Your situation seems to be moot.

Comment: Say the density of states of a fermionic system is given to be 
\[ g(E) =
    \begin{cases}
        0 & \text{if } E < -E_0 \\
        \frac{2n_0}{E^2_0} |E|   & \text{if } -E_0 \leq E \leq E_0 \\
        0 & \text{if } E > E_0
    \end{cases}
\]
where $E_0 (>0)$ is a given energy, and $n_0$ is number density of the fermions. This gives us the chemical potential at $T=0$ to be $0$. But I wonder what happens at any arbitrary finite temperature.